# I'm trying to drop a no longer used read/write group role but it says a function is owned by it that I cannot really find

Tags: postgresql

The server here is AWS PostgreSQL-Aurora v.11.11. I'm attempting to standardize the read only and read-write groups between all my environments so that SQL scripts which need to set privileges have no changes between environments. Currently they do need to change. Here's the problem:

```
-- The eg_rw role is a group read-write role with no login privileges.
drop role eg_rw;
ERROR:  role "eg_rw" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  owner of function generate_manifest_script()
```

OK, so I look for the function using:

```
SELECT string_agg('ALTER FUNCTION '|| oid::regprocedure || ' OWNER TO foo;', E'\n') AS ddl
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_proc
WHERE  pronamespace = 'public'::regnamespace
-- AND relowner <> 'foo'::regrole
-- AND proname ~~ 'f_%';
```

But that function does not appear in the list of functions produced. Nor have I been successful just trying to alter the owner using:

```
alter function generate_manifest_script() owner to eg_readwrite;
```

any ideas how to set it to the new group?

Comment: What about using `reassign owned`?

Comment: Completely slipped my mind, I guess it was way too early on the east coast when I posted this. The reassign owned by worked perfectly, and I have since dropped the old unused role. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @user188401 out of curiosity, was it in the public schema?